# How to get JSON data output on backend using API?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, json, response

In here I have not experience with JSON on Magento. So I need to know useful links or tips to learn that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find more details about Magento API's in below links:

> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html
>   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/response_formats.html
>   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html [Soap API]

This will help you for kickstart.